# Is it able to compile Julia script using PyCall.pyimport?

Tags: julia, pycall

I have to compile a Julia script and use opencv-python in it.
If it is feasible, how to compile?
What should I use? >PackageCompiler?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand your question. Are you aware of https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/da4/tutorial_julia.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be possible with PackageCompiler.jl. You will likely need to set up some artifacts as detailed here: https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/apps/#Artifacts-1

You can find out more about the Julia Artifacts system here: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/artifacts/

It may also be worth opening an issue and asking on the PackageCompiler.jl repo if there has been any work or tests with combining Julia and Python via PackageCompiler so as to avoid going down a dead end.